# geom_text overwrites entire map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, ggmap, geom-text

I am very new to working with spacial data with R. So I was hoping someone could point out where I am making a mistake.

The map works perfectly without the geom_text element. However, when I try to label the different regions on my map, the whole plot becomes black.

```
#First function loads spacial data, second loads arguments data
geo_data <- readOGR(dsn = file.choose(), layer = "CIV_adm01")
population_data <- read.csv(file.choose(), stringsAsFactors = `FALSE) #load
```

new attributes 
    population_data <- as.factor(population_data$phones)

```
# merge on common variable, here called 'NAME_1'
m <- merge(geo_data, population_data, by='NAME_1')

# saves shapefile in directory
shapefile(m, "path/merged.shp")

m_f <- fortify(m) #defines polygons, but loses atributes of the data
m$id <- row.names(m) #needed for join, extracts ID column
m_f <- left_join(m_f, m@data) # join the data

#change "fill" to variable you wish to analyze
map <- ggplot(m_f, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = phones)) +
geom_polygon() +
coord_equal() +
geom_text(aes(x=long,y=lat,label=NAME_1), data = m_f, size=3, alpha = 0.3) +
labs(x = "", y = "",
fill = "Concentration of Phones") + #title of legend
ggtitle("Phones per region") #title of map

#Map Style 1: Blue color
map + scale_fill_gradient(high = "#132B43", low = "#56B1F7", space = "Lab",
                      na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar")
```

This is the result I get.

[image]

Comment: You're essentially plotting the same text for _every_ lat/lon. You actually don't need to join the data as you are either, but without providing a minimal reproducible example it's going to be difficult to show you the exact error of your ways (unless someone is that desperate to accrue SO rep).

Comment: How do I remove the over-plotting for every lat/lon? Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: let me direct you to the most salient portion of my comment: "_…but without providing a minimal reproducible example…_"

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem myself.